# How are academic relations between mainland China and Taiwan?

Tags: politics, china

Both mainland China and Taiwan have internationally notable universities. How are the relations between their academic research communities?

Does getting involved (as a Westerner) with either of these research communities lead to political obstacles regarding the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relationship between the Chinese and Taiwanese academic research communities are generally friendly from my personal experience (a family member of mine is a professor at a Taiwanese university, and has collaborations with Chinese universities).

As far as I know, getting involved in the research community does not get you into political obstacles as long as you are not doing research in politics (which the Chinese government might be more sensitive to).